# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Two submit buttons - one should open a new tab, the other shouldn't

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So, I have two submit buttons with different values, and one should open a new tab on submit (for a preview), the other should not.

How could this be achieved? With JS or something?

(I'm using Razor.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the attribute of `formtarget="_blank"` on the button.

Comment: This worked, although I had to use the attribute `formtarget="_blank"`. Thanks!